# How to get element by name in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to get Element by name in vb.net

HTML Code:

```
<input name="domains[]" value="gamesolutionz.com" type="text">
```

VB.net:

```
Private Sub FlatTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatTextBox1.TextChanged
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("domains[]").SetAttribute("value", FlatTextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: is it asp.net ??????????????

Comment: it's vb.net ...

Comment: but what is front end tech , asp.net ?

Comment: What i am trying to do is I am using the VB to write something on the box of a website having only name as you can see in the html code

Comment: hi updated my answer , you have to try other method GetElementsByName as name only exist for element

Answer (score 1):

```
<input name="domains[]" value="gamesolutionz.com" type="text">
```

you are trying to acess element by ID but there is no ID present on that input element that is the reason you are not able to access that element

you need to try out

```
Private doc As HtmlDocument = webBrowser1.Document

Private elems As HtmlElementCollection = doc.All.GetElementsByName("domains[]")

Private elem As HtmlElement = elems(0)
```

Comment: Its HTML actually i am trying to get element id by name in VB

Comment: @AleemIqbal - add runat="server" and try it out

Comment: I am working on the second code first one is from a website

Comment: Getting the following error: GetElementsByName is not a member of HTML Document

Comment: Somehow the code worked but nothing happens when i write something on Text Box

Comment: ok, are you getting right elemtn here Private elem As HtmlElement = elems(0) , can you check elems(0) is element that you want tor refer

Comment: Private Sub FlatTextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatTextBox2.TextChanged
        Dim doc As HtmlDocument = WebBrowser1.Document
        Dim elems As HtmlElementCollection = doc.All.GetElementsByName("domains[]")
        Dim elem As HtmlElement = elems(FlatTextBox1.Text)
    End Sub

Comment: you have to do this Dim elem As HtmlElement = elems(0)...not this Dim elem As HtmlElement = elems(FlatTextBox1.Text),this is wrong try elems(0)

Comment: So how will i enter my text in the input field then?

Answer (score 0):

Finally Done it myself:
        Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

```
    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements

        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("name") = "domains[]" Then

            webpageelement.SetAttribute("value", FlatTextBox2.Text)

        End If

    Next
```